# Performing a selector stored in class

Tags: objective-c, selector, uipickerview

I'm using the classes defined below to hold a selector and a picker. On the didSelectRow method for the picker I want to perform the selector. However I keep getting "unrecognized selector sent to instance" exception when I use the picker to change the row.

I have tried changing the declaration of the selector to "SEL *theSelector" but this brings no joy as when performSelector is called theSelector is NULL.

Any fixes/ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Class with selector:

```
@implementation ClassA{
    UIPickerView *thePicker;
    SEL theSelector;
}

-(id)initWithView:(UIView*)theView{
    thePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    thePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    thePicker.delegate = self;
    thePicker.dataSource = self;
    [theView addSubview:thePicker];

    theSelector = NULL;
}

-(void)setSelector:(SEL)selector{
    theSelector = selector;
}

-(void)performTheSelector{
    if (theSelector != NULL) {
        [self performSelector:theSelector onThread:[NSThread currentThread] withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:  (NSInteger)component {
    [self performTheSelector];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return 10;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return @"Some Row";
}
```

Class that creates instance of ClassA and sets selector:

```
@implementation ClassB{
}

-(void)initWithView:(UIView*)theView{
    ClassA *objectA = [ClassA alloc] initWithView:theView]];
    [objectA setSelector:@selector(theSelectorMethod:)];
}

-(IBAction)theSelectorMethod:(id)sender{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: It should not be declared `SEL *`. What is the unrecognized selector from the error message? The `SEL` that's in the ivar, or something else? Why are you doing this? (Note also that you don't need to initialize ivars to 0 -- that's done by `alloc`. Also, your `init` needs to `return self`.)

Comment: The exception is raised on the line:
    [self performSelector:theSelector onThread:[NSThread currentThread] withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: But what's the full text of the error message? What is the unrecognized selector itself?

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ClassA theSelectorMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d391b0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling the selector on `ClassA`, but the selector is a method on `ClassB`.

By saying `[self performSelector:]`, you're essentially saying 'call this method on the current object' - but the current object is of type `ClassA`, and`theSelectorMethod` is part of `ClassB` instead.

You'll need to also pass in a reference to the object that you want to call the selector on - `setTarget:` or something similar. Then, in your `performTheSelector` method, you'd do `[objectB performSelector:...]` instead.

However, take a look at the common Objective-C design patterns of [target-action](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html) and [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) - these are very widely used throughout Cocoa and both achieve the sort of functionality you're after.